# vestido cor-de-rosa e casaco cinza

Tags: português-brasileiro

Tem diferença entre *vestido **cor-de-rosa*** e *vestido **rosa***?

No texto há:

> Comprei um vestido *cor-de-rosa* e um casaco *cinza*.

Não entendo o porquê as cores estão sendo usados desse jeito.

Comment: ! Adoro tuas perguntas. Parece-me que estás a aprender portugues! Eu estou sempre aprendendo a falar inglês e comecei o Francês e tenho várias dificuldades e questões parecidas com as tuas!

Comment: Peixoto! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Tambem existe: laranja y cor-de-laranja. Deve ter outras que não me vêm a cabeça agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há diferença nenhuma. Tanto faz utilizar:

- Comprei um vestido de cor-de-rosa; ou
- Comprei um vestido cor-de-rosa; ou
- Comprei um vestido rosa.

O termo **(de) cor de** está implícito em *vestido rosa* e *casaco cinza*.

O que ocorre no exemplo é a aplicação de uma figura de sintaxe chamada de [*elipse*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/search?q=elipse), que — para a gramática — é quando um termo, mesmo oculto, fica subentendido facilmente por ter sido mencionado ou sugerido sugerido anteriormente, ou ainda por ser depreendido pela situação ou contexto.

De acordo com *Bechara*, em *"Moderna Gramatica Portuguesa"*, a [elipse](/questions/tagged/elipse) que ocorre com mais frequência é:

- a da preposição em algumas circunstâncias adverbiais compreendida pelo contexto

  - *Domingo* irás à festa
  - O tecido custava dez reais *o metro*.
  - Deus não dá *para ócios ou desperdícios*
- a da preposição (ou conjunção integrante) antes do conectivo que introduz as orações de complemento relativo e completivas nominais

  - Preciso (de) que venhas aqui.
  - Quis defendê-la, mas Capitu não me deixou, continuou a chamar-lhe beata e carola, em voz tão alta que *tive medo fosse* ouvida dos pais.
- a da preposição de em construções do tipo *vestido **cor-de-rosa*** por *vestido **de cor de rosa***; pode-se também omitir toda a expressão ***de cor de***: ***vestido rosa***.

> **Adendo:** Apesar de o termo *cor-de-rosa* possuir hífen, os restantes das cores são escritas sem: `cor de café`, `cor de limão` etc.

**Atualização:**

De acordo com a [Academia Brasileira de Letra](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/abl-responde):

> **Pergunta :** Olá a todos, Recentemente estava lendo um texto e eis que encontro a seguinte oração: *"Comprei um vestido de cor-de-rosa"*. Ao ler esse trecho, surgiram-me algumas dúvidas. 1) A oração está de acordo com a gramática? 2) Há diferenças entre *"vestido de cor-de-rosa"*, *"vestido cor-de-rosa"* e *"vestido rosa"*? Grato.
>
> **Resposta :** Prezado Valdeir, são formas de expressar. O mais convencional é vestido rosa, mas não há erros nas outras formas.

<sup>[**Fonte**](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6260.md)</sup>

Comment: Pela pergunta percebe-se que _vestido_ está a ser usado como um nome, não um verbo. Por isso _vestido **de** cor-de-rosa_ não é uma opção.

Comment: @Artefacto De acordo com o gramático [**Evanildo Bechara**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Moderna+Gram%C3%A1tica+Portuguesa&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjduPvesPvkAhWXGLkGHb2AA6YQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=vestido%20de%20cor%20de%20rosa&f=false) é possível utilizar `vestido de cor de` (apesar de ele não especificar se o termo vestido é do verbo vestir).

Comment: Ademais, no [**A dictionary of the Portuguese and English languages**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=-ocSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PP451&dq=%22de+cor+de%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGpqaQs_vkAhX7G7kGHSgfBbU4HhDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22de%20cor%20de%22&f=false) é possível encontrar o seguinte trecho *"Purple, adj. purpureo, cousa de purpura, ou de cor de purpura."* e também *estofo de cor de púrpura*.

Comment: No [**Diccionario geral da lingoa Portugueza de Algibeira: Supplemento, Volume 5**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=sfdDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA199&dq=%22de+cor+de%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0xaXpsvvkAhVzILkGHcShDBA4FBDoAQhBMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22de%20cor%20de%22&f=false), o autor afirma que o significado do adjetivo *lactigero* é *“que contém sucos lácteos, ou de cor de leite”*. Por fim, há outro exemplo no livro [**Memórias de um sargento de milícias**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=KbdcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT96&ved=0ahUKEwj0xaXpsvvkAhVzILkGHcShDBA4FBDoAQhgMAk#v=onepage&q=%22de%20cor%20de%22&f=false)

Comment: hmm _um vestido de cor de leite_ ou até mesmo _um vestido de cor de laranja_ não me parecem muito mal, mas _um vestido de cor-de-rosa_ é para mim no mínimo muito marginal, provavelmente porque _cor-de-rosa_ forma uma unidade de sentido mais forte.

Comment: Concordo com o @Artefacto. No [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) encontrei no sXX uma dúzia ou isso de *[nome] de cor de café, de cor de limão* etc., mas nenhum *[nome] de cor-de-rosa*; mas encontrei uns cento e tal *[nome] cor-de-rosa*.

Comment: @Jacinto O termo `de cor de` é pouco usado, mas é possível encontrar alguns livros no *Google Books* com utiliza esse termo. [*Reputação arruinada*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DNeMBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&hl=pt-BR&q="laços%20de%20cor-de-rosa"), [*Sonhos à meia-noite*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=EbGhlniVtnwC&pg=PT53&hl=pt-BR&q="de%20cor-de-rosa"#v=snippet&q="de%20cor-de-rosa"&f=false) e [*A Casa De Geórgia*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=qdg4BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq="de+cor-de-rosa"&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWlrbVif7kAhUDIbkGHbC3BY84FBDoAQhYMAc).

Comment: Para não restar dúvidas, mandei um e-mail para um professor de gramática e para a *Academia Brasileira de Letras*. Esta, no entanto, demora *um pouco* para responder.

Comment: Adendo: No site Corpus do Português é possível encontrar `sapatos de cor-de-rosa`, termo utilizado no livro *Memórias de um sargento de milícias*, que foi supramencionado.

Comment: Eu não disse que ninguém alguma vez escrevesse *[nome] de cor-de-rosa* (o *Memórias de um sargento de milícias* é de 1853; eu restringi ao sXX para apanhar os padrões mais recentes ). Mas então, no Corpus tens cerca de 230 *[nome] cor-de-rosa* contra 1 *[nome] de cor-de-rosa* no sXIX, e cento tal contra zero no sXX. No Google Books, entre *casa(s)/flor(es)/camisa(s) cor-de-rosa* tens uns 210 contra zero *[mesmas coisas] de cor-de-rosa*. A meu ver, não podes dizer que "tanto faz utilizar" um como o outro; porque um é a maneira normal de falar, o outro é raro.

Comment: @Artefacto - Exatamente. Comparemos "vestido cor-de-rosa" com "vestido da cor da rosa mais fresca da alvorada", em que a preposição não pode ser suprimida.

Answer (score 1):

Não há diferença. "Cor-de-rosa" e "rosa" são sinônimos em contextos que implicam que se trata de uma cor. O mesmo ocorre com "cor de laranja" e "laranja". Podes dizer "vestido cor de laranja" ou "vestido laranja".

**Não** podes dizer "vestido de cor-de-rosa" na acepção da tua frase, ao contrário do que sugere a resposta aceita. "Vestido de cor-de-rosa" se traduz para o inglês como "dressed in pink", o que é diferente de "pink dress", que é como se traduz o teu exemplo.

Já "cinza" é usualmente "cinza" mesmo. Talvez antigamente tenha sido "cor de cinza", e se alguém disser ou escrever assim, certamente será entendido. Mas não é usual.

Comment: Encontram-se uns *cor de cinza* por aí, em livros, mas eu também não me lembro de alguma vez ter ouvido, e são raros comparados com *cinzento*. Sempre pensei que fosse simplesmente um simplificação de *cinzento*.